# How is python running faster than C and C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, performance, performance-testing

I have made simple program which just prints 1 million numbers on screen, python was taking about 5.2 seconds.
I thought C and C++ should do it faster but both are taking about 8 seconds every time I run. How these are slower than python?

python code:

```
import time

start = time.time()

i = 0
while i < 1000000:
    print(i)
    i += 1

time_taken = time.time() - start
print(("Program took %s seconds." % (time_taken)))
```

> Program took 5.204254150390625 seconds.

C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i )
        printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

> Time taken: 8.582 seconds.

C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i)
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

> Time taken: 8.778 seconds.

While when I run this:

```
import time

start = time.time()

print(*range(1000000))

time_taken = time.time() - start
print(("Program took %s seconds." % (time_taken)))
```

> Program took 60.77405118942261 seconds.

How is python's built in function is working slower than trivial version of program?

Comment: 1) Too broad. 2) Which Python version? Did you try `xrange` if that is Python2?

Comment: In Python 2, the `range` function has to build the entire list in memory first, then iterate over it. As for why your C and C++ programs are slower, are you compiling with optimizations on?

Comment: You're flushing the buffer for each single number in the C++ version. Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`. But it is IO dominated, so don't expect it one language to be significantly faster than the other.

Comment: Timing IO is kind of silly.  All sorts of things can make a difference.  For instance does `print` in python flush the buffer?

Comment: @rici: I doubt that would make much of a difference. `printf` is not compiled and that should take most of the time.

Comment: @chepner: it's python 3 and OP wrote *range(1000000) which explicitly unrolls the generator as a very long list of arguments.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It's the same in C and Python actually.

Comment: I think Python caches the first few popular numbers, so it has a head start.

Comment: @olaf: you're right; actually none of this is relevant.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It prints the line instantly with the line-break. But I agree, there is not much of a point here. Load/linking can take the majority; I don't see any timing code in the C or C++ version, while the Python code takes the times **after** all this.

Comment: @KerrekSB 200+ numbers out of a million isn't going to account for a 30-40% speedup.

Comment: Downvoters: Just because the questioner doesn't fully understand the ramifications of their testing methodology doesn't make this a bad question. It is entirely legitimate to ask, and the answer might be helpful to other people. IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the last case (see below), what you are timing in this test is basically the console application which you are using, not the C/C++/Python programs themselves.

```
If you redirect the output, you'll find a huge difference:

$ time ./loop >/dev/null

real    0m0.096s
user    0m0.092s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time ./loop >/tmp/million.txt
 time ./loop >/tmp/million.txt

real    0m0.116s
user    0m0.078s
sys     0m0.019s

$ time ./loop
0
1
# ...Many lines of output not included
999998
999999

real    0m6.465s
user    0m0.202s
sys     0m0.708s
```

The reason your last Python example is so slow is that you have used `*range(1000000)` to explicitly unroll the generator into a million arguments to `print`. That forces Python to create enormous lists, and it is not optimized for that particular case. It's better to use generators to generate.

I suspect that the difference between the initial Python timing and the C timing is an artefact of the testing methodology. The first one uses Python to measure the time, which means that it measures the time from program startup to when Python has finished sending the data to the console. However, you presumably used the `time` command to time the C program, which means that you are measuring the time until the last line was actually output to the console. Since there is a largish kernel buffer involved, the difference will be quite large. Try using `time` to time both programs; when I did, the difference disappeared.